# How can I end a Do Loop after some sort of user input?

Tags: vbscript

Any kind of user input will do. Here's the code I have so far.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim Account
Account = 111111
WScript.Sleep 5000

Do
WScript.Sleep 400
WshShell.SendKeys "drill "
WshShell.SendKeys Account
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Account = Account + 1
Loop
```

Basically it's a code guesser (for a game) and I want to be able to interrupt it with any kind of user input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have any direct solution. Below code seeks for user interaction after 50 iterations. If yes, control exits from do loop. You can play around with other ways to interrupt the loop and of course you can change the counter as per your need.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim counter
Dim Account
Dim msgResult

counter = 0
Account = 111111
WScript.Sleep 5000

Do
WScript.Sleep 400
WshShell.SendKeys "drill "
WshShell.SendKeys "drill "
WshShell.SendKeys Account
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Account = Account + 1
If counter = 50 Then  'get user input after 50 iterations
  msgResult = MsgBox("Do you want to exit?", vbYesNo)
  If msgResult = vbYes Then 'if yes
       Exit Do
  End If
End If
counter = counter + 1
If counter > 101 then
    counter =0
End If
Loop
```